# how can I use pygame to surface a image with a title text on top of the image?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

how can I use pygame to surface a image with a title text on top of the image?
I want to use pygame to create an object like a superman(image) to move and at the same time ,I want there is a text on top of the  superman(image), and can move with the superman(image)
What can I do?

Comment: It's possible to use a `pygame.font.Font` to create a surface containing some text, with a transparent background.   This can then be drawn on top the image every re-paint.  It would be more efficient to put the text into the image (assuming the image is a surface too) once, and just draw the image+text combined surface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pygame.font](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html) to write text or to have more control over it, you can use [pygame.freetype](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html) instead.

Example with pygame.font

```
font = pygame.SysFont("name of font or None", size)
### or ###
font = pygame.Font("path to file", size)

text_img = font.render(text, True, color)

# if needed, you can get the size
size = text_img.get_size()
width = text_img.get_width()
height = text_img.get_height()

# you can blit the text like your other images
window = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))

window.blit(text_img, (x, y))
```

Example with pygame.freetype

```
import pygame
import pygame.freetype # <- needed

font = pygame.freetype.SysFont("name of font or None")
### or ###
font = pygame.freetype.Font("path to file")

# get size before rendering
rect = font.get_rect(text, size=0)

# render on an existing surface
font.render_to(surf, (x, y), text, color, size=10)

# you can enter additonal parameters
# bgcolor=None, style=STYLE_DEFAULT, rotation=0
```

If you run into any problems or need more info, you should use the [pygame wiki](https://www.pygame.org/docs).

Comment: the second example i very good and solved my problem,thanks.